# What were the uses of the RTGs in the Apollo spacecrafts?

Tags: apollo-program, thermal, thermal-control, rtg, apollo-13

I was listening to the [Plutonium episode of "the Elements"](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p025ynjy) on the BBC, and between 07:00 and 08:30 they talked about uses of plutonium such as spacecraft power and heat. While the returning astronauts in Apollo 13 were not actually "keeping warm" using the RTG, I didn't realize that the spacecraft actually had RTGs.

In [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/75/12102) I found that indeed the Apollo 13 [LEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Module) contained an RTG.

Was it just the one RTG per LEM that was used in Apollo spacecraft, or were there more? Were they just used as a passive, steady source of heat to insure things didn't get too cold, or for a source of power also?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The RTGs powered the [Apollo Lunar Surface Experiments Package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Surface_Experiments_Package).

This is also the first thing that comes up when you google "Apollo RTG".

Comment: Is that the only use? Only Apollo missions that carried surface experiment packages carried RTGs? They were never parts of the spacecraft themselves?

Comment: That is correct.  The wikipedia article gives a timeline showing how the RTG fuel elements were not even inserted until the astronauts were on the Lunar surface.

Comment: The *From the Earth to the Moon* TV miniseries episode on Apollo 13 touches on this. I think the explanation given there is *"it's a battery for the lunar surface experiments"*.